# How to Store Facebook App Access Token in Mobile App Client?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-access-token, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-app-requests

To request the FB app events API, I would need to use an app access token.

It says in the doc "The Facebook SDK automatically logs app installs, app sessions, and in-app purchases."

And "Do not store your app access token on the client" also "Again, for security, app access token should never be hard-coded into client-side code, doing so would give everyone who loaded your webpage or decompiled your app full access to your app secret, and therefore the ability to modify your app. This implies that most of the time, you will be using app access tokens only in server to server calls."

Then how can I make a request from the app SDK if I am not storing/hard coding the app access token in the mobile app code?

Documentation is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/app-event-api/

Comment: Make a request to your server, and make the request to Facebook’s API from there …?

Comment: I think that defeats the purpose of an SDK, right? With an SDK we want to issue an RPC from SDK to facebook server directly...

Comment: No, it doesn’t. There’s plenty of use cases, for making client-side calls using the user access token, or their page tokens. Putting your client secret into client-side code is an absolute no-go, even if you did not use any SDK, and just made your API calls using any HTTP library.

Comment: So you are saying, client (mobile app in this case) should make a request to my backend to retrieve the access token, and the the client/mobile app will issue a request to facebook with the access token?

Comment: No, let the server side make the API request.